# WiX Condition on installing

Tags: wix, wix3

I've been scouring StackOverflow, blogs and FireGiants tutorials for clear answers for a few days now. It seems everyone has a slightly different way of doing things with WiX and there's never enough code to actually answer the issue I'm having.

I have an installer that will create folders, copy files down, register DCOM dlls, add Services and registry keys. All this works fine. Even managed to finally craft a custom UI from scratch that'll compile and doesn't have excessive dialogs to annoy me.

What I can't for the life of me figure out is using the Condition tag to have an option to either install just the client files, or both the client and server.

I have a dialog with two buttons that set a property, and that property is to be used in the condition on which files to install.

**DlgWelcome.wxs:**

```
<Fragment>
    <UI Id="WelcomeUI">
      <Property Id="INSTALLCLIENT" Value="0" Secure="yes"/>
      <Property Id="INSTALLSERVER" Value="0" Secure="yes"/>

      <Dialog Id="WelcomeDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="!(loc.WelcomeDlgTitle)" NoMinimize="yes">

        <Control Type="Text" Id="WelcomeDlgTxt" Width="350" Height="30" X="10" Y="60" Text="!(loc.WelcomeDlgText)" />

        <Control Type="PushButton" Id="InstallClient" Width="350" Height="50" X="10" Y="90">
          <Text>!(loc.ClientInstallBtnText)</Text>
          <Publish Property="INSTALLCLIENT" Value="1"/>
          <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="ProgressDlg"/>
        </Control>

        <Control Type="PushButton" Id="InstallServer" Width="350" Height="50" X="10" Y="150">
          <Text>(loc.InstallServerBtnText)</Text>
          <Publish Property="INSTALLSERVER" Value="1"/>
          <Publish Property="INSTALLCLIENT" Value="1"/>
          <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="ProgressDlg" />
        </Control>
    </UI>
</Fragment>
```

**Product.wxs:**

```
...
<Feature Id="Installation" Title="Install Stuffs" Display="expand">
      <Feature Id="ServerInstall" Level="1" >
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="ServerFiles" />
        <ComponentRef Id="RegistryForServer"/>
        <Condition Level="0">INSTALLSERVER</Condition>
      </Feature>

      <Feature Id="ClientInstall" Level="1" >
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="ClientFiles"/>
        <ComponentRef Id="RegistryForClient"/>
        <Condition Level="0">INSTALLCLIENT</Condition>
      </Feature>
</Feature>

<UI>
      <InstallUISequence>
        <CostInitialize />
        <FileCost />
        <CostFinalize />
        <Show Dialog="WelcomeDlg" After="CostFinalize"/>
        <ExecuteAction />
      </InstallUISequence>    
</UI>
```

Some of the things I've tried that I've seen as Verified solutions various posts have had to apparently fix a similar problem (Can't confirm if they have the same version of WiX in use or not, but none work):

- Had the Property declared in different ways: all caps to be accessible from the command line(which I don't use),  and .... None of which seem to work.
- Moved the conditions to the individual Components. Did nothing.
- Moved the Publish property tags around, before and after the NewDialog. No effect.
- Made the Property Secure. Nothing.

So I'm at my wits end with this. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong so I can finish this installer and hopefully never look at WiX ever again?

Comment: Is it necessary for you to have INSTALLCLIENT as a condition if you want the client files to be installed in either case? I doubt that this will actually solve your problem, but it might make the code marginally less complicated.

Comment: It is not, come to think of it. I'll remove that. It was more for future proofing than anything, maybe in the future there might be more options required in the installer. But the issue remains that I'm missing something on how the Condition works.

Comment: Try my solution below, if that doesn't work, try and look into exactly how the conditions tags' level attribute works, as I'm fairly sure that's where the issue lies.

Comment: I've had the Feature on level 0 and the Condition on level 1, and the other way around. Basically Feature level 0 and it's not installed by default, but have the Condition on level 1 to install it. Additionally, I've tried to just set the default property INSTALLLEVEL and set the levels accordingly, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Control Type="PushButton" Id="InstallClient" Width="350" Height="50" X="10" Y="90">
    <Text>!(loc.ClientInstallBtnText)</Text>
    <Publish Property="INSTALLLEVEL" Value="2"/>
    <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="ProgressDlg"/>
</Control>

<Control Type="PushButton" Id="InstallServer" Width="350" Height="50" X="10" Y="150">
  <Text>(loc.InstallServerBtnText)</Text>
  <Publish Property="INSTALLLEVEL" Value="5"/>
  <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="ProgressDlg" />
</Control>

...

<Feature Id="Installation" Title="Install Stuffs" Display="expand">
  <Feature Id="ServerInstall" Level="3" >
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="ServerFiles" />
    <ComponentRef Id="RegistryForServer"/>
  </Feature>

  <Feature Id="ClientInstall" Level="1" >
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="ClientFiles"/>
    <ComponentRef Id="RegistryForClient"/>
  </Feature>
```

I don't think you're really supposed to modify INSTALLLEVEL like this, but it might work for now.

Comment: I thought this to be a good idea that would reduce the number of Properties required. But no change on the conditions: If the Condition tag is used, nothing gets installed that is in that Feature.

Comment: Oh hang on, why do you have two features nested under another Feature tag?

Comment: Initially no, I had the server and client files on separate Features one after another. Then I put them together under a common nestling Feature called "Install". This was another thing that I saw in other solutions and I thought maybe that was it. No change, whether the super-feature had a level or not.

Comment: I mean, if you have two features under a single feature you might not be able to independently change the install levels of the two sub-features.

Comment: No change when features are separated and not nested. Level="2" on server does not install, client which is on Level="1" will.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is pretty much standard Windows installer/MSI and not specific to WiX. The version of WiX will not matter.

What you'll want to do is set the default [INSTALLLEVEL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369536(v=vs.85).aspx.) in the installer. Generally 100 is a good level to set it at.

For each of your features (Client or Server) set the Level attribute in the [Feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368585(v=vs.85).aspx) table.

If the Feature's Level is less than the INSTALLLEVEL for the installer it will install that feature. All you have to do at run time is set this property to determine what features you want installed.